# How do you load a plugin in a elasticsearch servlet

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch

I am running elastic search as servlet (ie using NodeServlet). But can't find any pointer to some docs to include plugins somehow.

Any hints welcome!

Comment: why not include them at compile time? e.g. via pom.xml

Comment: well, i am using Grapes in groovy. The servlet will register automatically the plugins?

Comment: i have tried and it works. I have even added it at runtime (well the groovy way...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the relevant plugin jar file (and if it deps, them as well). All the elasticsearch plugins  are hosted in the same elasticsearch maven repo if you are using maven.

Comment: yes, but how the nodeservlet will find them out. It won't be automatic i guess. (unless OSGIfied?)

Comment: ok just tried it it sounds it works with the twitter river, Thanks for the answer!